# How do I get the selected item from drop down list and submit it to my Details view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an mvc razor form. What i want is to submit the user's selection from Items dropdown list and navigate to Details view in order to access the chosen item's information.

Currently when i click the submit button i navigate succesfully to Details view but there is absolutely no data showing there.

Can you please help me?

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Details", "Bookings", FormMethod.Post))
{
<fieldset>
    <legend> Type/Item</legend>
    <label for="Items">Item Types </label>
    @Html.DropDownList("department", ViewBag.ItemTypesList as SelectList, "Select a Type", new { id = "ItemTypeID" })
    <div id="ItemsDivId">
        <label for="Items">Items </label>
        <select id="ItemsID" name="Items"></select>
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type ="submit" value="Submit" id="SubmitID" />
    </p>
 </fieldset>
}


    <script type="text/javascript">

        $('#ItemTypeID').on('change', function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetItemTypeForm")',
            data: { itemTypeId: $('#ItemTypeID').val() },
            success: function (results) {
                var options = $('#ItemsID');
                options.empty();
                options.append($('<option />').val(null).text("- Select an Item -"));
                $.each(results, function () {
                    options.append($('<option />').val(this.ItemsID).text(this.Value));
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Controller:**

```
 public ActionResult Details(string id)
        {
            var item = db.Items.Find(id);

            return View(item);
        }

[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult GetItemTypeForm(string itemTypeId)
        {
            //pseudo code
            var data = from s in db.Items
                       where s.ItemType.ItemTypeName == itemTypeId
                       select new { Value = s.ItemName, ItemsID = s.ItemId };


            return Json(data);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `Items` in Details method if you want to get Items value

```
  public ActionResult Details(int Items)
    {
        var item = db.Items.Find(Items);

        return View(item);
    }
```

Comment: This is not the drop down list i want to get the value from :) i want to get it from here : <select id="ItemsID" name="Items"></select>

Comment: Thank you very much Murali !  I used int Items and works fine :)

Answer (score 1):

A dropdown only sends simple values. The name usually have to match the name of the parameter in the method signature. Remember that it is the name attribute that is the key in the querystring, and not the id attribute. Hence the use of department in this example and Items in @Murali's answer.

Try changing your details method to:

```
 public ActionResult Details(string department)
    {
        var item = db.Items.Find(department);

        return View(item);
    }
```

Comment: Why did you change `department` to `ItemTypeID`? You were correct with `department`, MVC uses a name to bind the value and not id :)

Comment: This is not the drop down list i want to get the value from :)
i want to get it from here :
<select id="ItemsID" name="Items"></select>

Comment: You didn't supply code for that one ;-) You should be able to apply thsi solution to the other dropdownlist. Just change the parameter name accordingly.

Comment: i am populating the second drop down list using jquery and i want use the value of this drop down list

Comment: i tried to use "ItemsID" for my Details view but wasnt getting anything :(

Comment: I need to get the selected value from the Items drop down list that i build using the jquery...

Comment: Do the value show up in HttpContext.Request.QueryString.AllKeys["Items"]?

Comment: Thank you for your time scheien, the correct answer was to use int Items :)